# how to display only those record for which data is present for inner query

Tags: soql

Here is my soql query

```
select id,name,lastmodifieddate,(select createddate,field,parentid from histories where createddate>=2016-03-01T01:02:03Z  and createddate<=2016-03-28T01:02:03Z order by  createddate asc) hist from enrollment__c limit 10
```

here is a screen shot of that

now first 5 rows has histories  values,  others are blank.
please suggest me query to display only first 5 records which has data.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
select id,name,lastmodifieddate,(select createddate,field,parentid from histories where createddate>=2016-03-01T01:02:03Z  and createddate<=2016-03-28T01:02:03Z order by  createddate asc) hist from enrollment__c where id in (select parentid from histories) limit 10
```

**Assumption and Explanation:**

The above query assumes `parentid` field in `histories` object points to `enrollment__c` object.

First the query after the where will execute and brings all the `parentid` available. Then the actual query runs with the filter of `parentid` and gets the `enrollment__c` records which have the `histories`.

SOQL relationship queries [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com).

Hope it helps.

Comment: i tried your solution.I am getting this error in workbench

Comment: sObject type 'histories' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: actually histories is standard history object for any parent object

Comment: History objects for any parent object will have the format of sobject__history for custom objects and sobjecthistory for standard objects. Try enrollment__history

Comment: yes now query is working but giving the same results as earlier.No change in query result

Comment: When i run the same query for a custom object in my org the results differs. Can you check by removing the limit 10 and try again.

Comment: Is there any way check not null for inner query result by giving alias?

Comment: Since you have filter condition of `createddate>=2016-03-01T01:02:03Z  and createddate<=2016-03-28T01:02:03Z` in in inner query, try adding the same in the outer query like `where id in (select id from enrollment__history where createddate>=2016-03-01T01:02:03Z  and createddate<=2016-03-28T01:02:03Z)`

Comment: Is there anything else i could help you?

Comment: yes please help me test class for that..i have to make test data for history object..which is not possible. I am able to create data for parent object but when i make changes(updating parent object) history object is not getting data,  is there any way out

Comment: Please take a look at this answer http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/4008/20832. If you still have questions, close this question and create a new one for that so we can track of it easily.