# Create AccountHistory record in test class

Tags: unit-test, accounthistory

Can we create the AccountHistory Reocrd in test class if it is possible plz post how ?

Comment: send test class and class code

Answer (score 2):

You **can not create History records of any object**.

Basically for creating them you have to **make changes in that particular object record and then query the history records**.

Comment: I don't think history records get created in testmethods

Answer (score 0):

AccountHistory Represents the history of changes to the values in the fields of an account. You can not create AccountHistory Reocrd .

**You can query AccountHistory record**. In test class you have to set seeAllData=true

```
SELECT CreatedDate,Field,Id,IsDeleted,NewValue,OldValue FROM AccountHistory
```

Answer (score 0):

[It is suggested that it is possible to create AccountHistory Record in test here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/139438/3716). However, you can't specify `NewValue` or `OldValue` fields values.

Still, it doesn't seem to be working for me: when I run code

```
@isTest class TestClass {
    static testMethod void testMetod() {
        Account a = new Account(Name = 'a');
        insert a;
        insert new AccountHistory(AccountId=a.Id, Field = 'Name');
    }
}
```

I see internal error  [image]

Maybe it is only error in my environment and it may work fine in your environment or in the future release.