# How to validate Old and New Values of ContactHistory in Test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I have an apex class which looks for the old and new values of contacthistory. I am writing a test class for this, but could not write data to Oldvalue and Newvalue. I also tried updating the field which is tracked in history, but that gives null value when I tried assert statement. Here is my class

```
for(ContactHistory ct: scope){
             if((ct.NewValue =='Test Data' && ct.OldValue =='Old Data')||
                (ct.NewValue == 'New Test Data' && ct.OldValue =='Old Data Listing'){
//do something
}}
```

How do I cover this if condition?

Here is my test class:

```
 Test.startTest();
        Contact c = new contact(lastname = 'test', email='email@mail.com');
             c.TrackedField__c ='OldData';
             c.AccountId = acc.Id;
        insert c;


         c.TrackedField__c ='Test Data'; 
         update c;
         Test.stopTest();

ContactHostory ch =[select contactid, OldValue, NewValue from ContactHistory where ContactId =: c.id and Field ='TrackedField__c' limit1]; //this is returning zero results
```

Comment: Hi there! I closed your question as a duplicate. There's a lot of great answers there, so make sure you read through them all to see which solution you'd like to use. If none of the answers are helpful, please let us know, and make an [edit] to distinguish your question from the previous one, and we'll be glad to help you out.

Comment: I tried the approach per the above, but couldn't resolve my issue

Comment: based on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/191666/2602, some SObjectField history objects are not supported by the Test.loadData feature - I see you are using Contact.  SFDC will not create field history records in a testmethod. Mocking them is challenging (see aforementioned link)

Comment: I am looking at validating the old value and new value. Per the solution above, it says old and new values are null, but in y case, I have string values to compare for old and new values. How do I achieve that?

Comment: @sfdc: Can you remove this as duplicate since the question is updated. Since it is marked duplicate though it is not, I dont think people can really look at it, since it is marked as "duplicate"

Comment: @user64977 and anyone else: please make sure you use the full user name, or I may not see the comments. Of the last four comments, I've only seen one. Aside from that, I still feel that this is a duplicate, since you've requested, I shall reopen the question. I cannot guarantee that you'll get any different answer, however. Field History can't ordinarily be written in a unit test without using an existing record.