# Testing Custom Object History Query Apex

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, lightning-web-components, code-coverage

I have the following APEX code I need tested and have found many topics regarding testing these methods but none seem to work.  Please if you have any tips on how to test this method it would be appreciated.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String getPreviousContractStatus(Id parentId) {

        // create new list of all previous Contract amounts
        List<String> oldValueList = new List<String>();

        //query for OldValue of Contract Status
        List<Contract__History> oldValuesContractStatus = [
                SELECT OldValue
                FROM Contract__History
                WHERE Field = 'Contract_Status__c'
                AND ParentId =: parentId
                ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
        ];

        // Remove Approval Requested value from list as it always will be OldValue
        // when using Close Contract button
        if(oldValuesCommitStatus.size() > 0){
            for(Contract__History cH : oldValuesContractStatus){
                if(cH.OldValue != 'Approval Requested') {
                    oldValueList.add(String.valueOf(cH.OldValue));
                }
            }
        }

        return oldValueList[0];

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated on how to test.

Comment: I do not believe that the history objects are tracked in the same transaction as the test, therefore it is almost impossible to rely on the table being available unless you mock the expectancies. I recommend you attempt a mock utility where you create the history record under the conditions in your requirements.

Comment: but OldValue and NewValue are not writeable, how to mock this?

Comment: Looks like this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4007/is-it-possible-to-test-apex-that-relies-on-field-history-tracking) aligns with my thinking. Have you tried this?

Comment: Hey Tsmith thanks for you help,  The problem is I need to get some kind of OldValue from a status field to complete code coverage for deployment,  I tried the first solution by process rows into database based on field, but need to run this through my method stated above for coverage and List Index Out of Bounds 0 shows up because the Contract I create in that sense still has no OldValues

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to test apex that relies on field history tracking?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4007/is-it-possible-to-test-apex-that-relies-on-field-history-tracking)