# How to write test class that retrieves the account history data?

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, lightning-web-components, accounthistory

I am using an apex class(HistoryManager) which has a method getHistoryRecords that takes 2 parameters namely a soql query(String) and a recordId(String) and calling it in the connectedCallBack() method of the LWC component.

I am not sure how to write a test class for this apex method and i'm having a hard time figuring out. Below is my apex code;

```
public with sharing class HistoryManager {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
   public static List<Object> getHistoryRecords(String soqlQuery, String recordId){
       String query = soqlQuery;
       String replacedQuery = query.replace('<<recordId>>',recordId);
       return Database.query(replacedQuery);
   }

}
```

Comment: Testing code that relies on history tracking is hard (and can be impossible). See [Is it possible to test apex that relies on history tracking](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4007/is-it-possible-to-test-apex-that-relies-on-field-history-tracking). This class that you've provided, however, doesn't strictly _need_ to query history. Just write a test that calls this `getHistoryRecords()` method, and pass a simple query to it instead (like `'SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id = <<recordId>>'`).

Comment: Hi Derek, Thanks for your reply..Actually i tried your method of writing the test. I am giving a input SOQL  like below in my test class and my main class replaces the string '<<recordId>>' with the actual id but still then i am getting error like "System.QueryException: expecting a colon, found '<' ". Do you have any idea why the database.query returns such error. Would like to know a solution. Thanks in advance

List<Object> accHist = HistoryManager.getHistoryRecords('SELECT Id FROM Account where Id= <<recordId>>', acc.id);